# Angular 4 CSS on document.createElement()

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, createelement

I try to create elements dynamically in Angular 4.

TS

```
const bookmark = document.createElement('a');
bookmark.className = 'bookmark';
```

SCSS

```
.bookmark {
  display: block;
  background: white;
  color: #999;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: 0.3s ease all;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD;
}
```

However the style do not apply on the element from the SASS file. If I add the style directly in the JS file, it works:

```
const bookmark = document.createElement('a');
bookmark.className = 'bookmark';

bookmark.style.display = 'block';
bookmark.style.background = 'white';
bookmark.style.color = '#999';
bookmark.style.padding = '20px';
bookmark.style.transition = '0.3s ease all';
bookmark.style.borderBottom = '1px solid #DDD';
```

If I create the element directly in the HTML file, it automatically gets a **_ngcontent-c1** attribute whilst the one created in TS misses this attribute (if I give it manually in Chrome Developer Tools - Element panel, it gets the style from SCSS).

```
<div class="bookmarks-list">
  <a class="bookmark">
    I am the bookmark
  </a>
</div>
```

My question is, how to apply the .bookmark class style from the SASS file to the created bookmark element in TS?

Comment: Why are you doing classical DOM with Angular at all?

Comment: Do you have a document template?

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi thanks for the question. I am new to Angular4, I try to create elements for the component view on _click_ event. What way do you suggest instead of _document.createElement()_?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't share the full code, but probably it's the problem with where you create your element, if it's inside a component, it might not reaching your css due to encapsulation , try to use something like below:

```
@Component({
// ...
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, //<<<<< this one!
styles: [
  // ...
]
})
export class HelloComponent {
// ...
}
```

For more info, visit the link below:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#view-encapsulation

Comment: Yes it is inside a component and changing the encapsulation mode really helped. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you. It works when I use innerHTML.